# editing html using javascript that calls php function that gets information from sql database.. complicated...

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

i am trying to edit a select list every time the list before it is being changed.
what i am trying to do is change the list already existing into another list, called by a php function, that generates a list of the new information it has from the first list and an sql database.

it's pretty hard to explain so here is my code:

the base of my code

```
//php & html
....

$cli = lastNameList();       //first list
$tli = firstNameList();   //second list

echo"

$cli
<div id='editHtml'>$tli</div>

";

....
```

functions (php)

```
//the functions

function lastNameList(){

$options="<select id='lastNames'>"; 

$sql="SELECT * FROM lastName";
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

$options.="<option value='blank'>-- last names --</option>" ;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$name=$row["name"]; 

$options.="<option value='$name'>$name</option>"; 
} 

$options.= "</SELECT>";
return "$options";
}


function firstNameList(){

$options="<select id='firstNames' style='margin-right:40px;'>";
```

having a problem over here:

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM firstName WHERE LastName ='lastNameSelectedGoesHere'";
//how do i get the value of the last name so i could make a query for it?

//using distinct to make sure there are no duplicates

$result=mysql_query($sql); 

$options.="<option value='blank'>-- first name --</option>" ;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$name=$row["Name"]; 
$options.="<option value='$name'>$name</option>"; 
} 

 $options.= "</SELECT>";
return "$options";
}
```

js (inside a php file if it matters)

```
echo"  <script type='text/javascript'>
$('#lastNames').change(function() {

 document.getElementById('eTech').innerHTML="; 

 $ll = firstNameList();
 echo"$ll;

});";
```

so as you can see my js file is in a php file, it does work, what i tried to do there, is generate a new first name list to come and replace the old one but i failed... anyone has an answer or suggestion to what i should do?

Comment: you can use JS to call PHP only if you're using AJAX or by submitting a Form

Comment: but as you can see, i am not trying to submit a form, i am trying to regenerate a new list to match the options of the first one, lets say the last name selected was 'cela' so the options might be 'anthony', 'nick' and other options that match it, and if i would change the first option, the second list would change as well and have different names, what can i do to get the result then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis isn't complicated at all using ajax & jquery!

A quick dirty way is to do this

```
<div id="firstName"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#lastNames').change(function() {
$('#firstName').load('getfirstname.php?lastname=' + $(this).val());
});
</script>
```

and for getfirstname.php page

```
$lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['lastname']);
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM firstName WHERE LastName ='$lastName'";


//using distinct to make sure there are no duplicates

$result=mysql_query($sql); 
$options="<select id='firstNames' style='margin-right:40px;'>";
$options.="<option value='blank'>-- first name --</option>" ;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$name=$row["Name"]; 
$options.="<option value='$name'>$name</option>"; 
} 

 $options.= "</SELECT>";
echo $options;
```

Here is a very simple page that shows how to execute php code using ajax and jquery.

```
<?
if(!isset($_GET['value'])):?>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<select id="select" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</options>
</select>

<div id="phpoutput"></div>

<script>
    $('#select').change(function() {
    $('#phpoutput').load('?value=' + $(this).val());
    });

</script>
<?else:
    $val = $_GET['value'];
    echo "$val sent to server. $val*3 = " . $val *3;
 ?>
<?endif;?>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, is there any other way? it doesn't seem to load anything on change...

Comment: @Baruch I have updated my answer and added a block of code that shows you an extremely basic ajax. This should give you an idea on how it works, and you can use this to implement what yo uneed

Comment: Thanks, ill try it later on when i get home, seems like it should work